# Set an option to be displayed at first position using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-select

I have a select element with some options:

```
<select id="choose">
    <option id="first" value='null'>choose</option>
    <option id="g1" value='1'>gate1</option>
    <option id="g2" value='2'>gate2</option>
</select>
```

The user selects an option and submits the form. The data is stored. 
Anytime the user comes back I want the previously saved option to be display
at the top of the select element, instead of choose.

I do it e.g. this way

```
$("#choose").val("2");
```

It just highlights the option in the list, but choose is still the first element. How do I accomplish that?

Comment: You can use php to set a cookie and then take that cookie, if there is one, process it and then put that option in

Comment: is there a server side to this? how are you loading the options in the html? or are they hardcoded?

Comment: I am working on an chrome extension, so this is just javascript/jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you want to move the selected item to the top after they select it.

Just bind to the change event and the find the selected option and prepend it to the `#choose`

```
var choose = $("#choose").bind('change',function(){
    choose.find('option:selected').prependTo(choose);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/petersendidit/ZuhqS/1/

Comment: Does this work with IE 11 ? I tried it but couldn't make it work. Could you please check and let me know where am I going wrong http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38773319/set-the-selected-option-as-the-first-option-in-the-selectbox

Answer (score 1):

```
var prevSelVal = 2;
if(prevSelVal!=0){
    var elem = $('#g' + prevSelVal).remove();
    $('#first').remove();
    $('#choose').prepend(elem);
}
```

The code above removes the element from the list and places it at the top. It also removes your 'choose' element.

Answer (score 0):

See: http://jsbin.com/ipewe/edit
Here's a sample...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Sandbox</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
body { background-color: #000; font: 16px Helvetica, Arial; color: #fff; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Hello from JS Bin</p>
  <p id="hello"></p>
  <select>
<option value="1" >Number 1</option>
<option value="2" selected="selected">Number 2</option>
<option value="3" >Number 3</option>
<option value="4" >Number 4</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('option:selected', 'select').removeAttr('selected').next('option').attr('selected', 'selected');
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

[`prepend`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) should do the trick:

```
var choose = $('#choose');
choose.val(2).prepend(choose.find('[value="2"]'));
```