# Set the selected option as the first option in the selectbox

Tags: html, select, internet-explorer-11, html-select, default

Open [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select) in IE to exactly understand the behavior that I will be describing and seek a hack for.

I have the following select list:

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

When I render this in **IE, drop-down behavior** of this changes compared to other browsers due to which some of the options are pushed above the **selectbox** while the others are pushed below (based on the selected option)

Since this is the **default behavior of IE**, what I am looking for is that the options should get **re-ordered** i.e. the option that a user selects should be made the first option. Check the image below:

[image]

Does anyone have a work-around for this ?

Also if anyone knows a hack to alter this default IE behavior, it would be great to know and learn that

Is this the right way ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var choose = $("#choose").bind('change',function(){alert("hello");
choose.find('option:selected').prependTo(choose);
});
});
</script>
<head>
<body>

<select id="choose">
<option value="choose">choose</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="opel">Opel</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: So far I haven't, but if there is a way to handle this using jQuery, I can try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method that works in Jquery:

*HTML*

```
<select id = "choose">
    <option value="null" name="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="1" name="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="2" name="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="3" name="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

*jQuery*

```
var choose = $("#choose").bind('change',function(){
    choose.find('option:selected').prependTo(choose);
});
```

([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4839374/6525260))

***FULL CODE***

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var choose = $("#choose").bind('change', function() {
        alert("hello");
        choose.find('option:selected').prependTo(choose);
      });
    });
  </script>

  <head>

    <body>

      <select id="choose">
        <option value="choose">choose</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="opel">Opel</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      </select>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: This helps. Thanks for a quick reply

Comment: Does this work with IE 11 ? While the functionality is absolutely fine. I am unable to make this work in IE 11

Comment: I have JS enabled on IE. Not sure what other settings might stop this. Could you please check my updated code in question. Did i missed something in my code?

Comment: How can I miss that.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
    <html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var selectedItem = $("#selectItem").bind('change', function () {
                selectedItem.find('option:selected').prependTo(selectedItem);
            });
        });
    </script>
    <head>
        <body>

            <select id="selectItem">
            <option value="1">one</option>
            <option value="2">two</option>
            <option value="3">three</option>
            <option value="4">four</option>
            </select>

        </body>
</html>
```

[image: click to see output screen][image: click to see output screen]

Thanks... :)